# python pandas sort columns after merge

Tags: python, pandas

I have merged two pandas dataframes with multiple overlapping columns.  I would like to put the overlapping columns side by side.

```
merge = df1.merge(df2, how='outer')
```

Output:

```
A,B,C,D,A_x,B_x,C_x,D_x
```

I would like the output to be:

```
A,A_x,B,B_x,C,C_x,D,D_x
```

I can do this explicitly but I have many columns and would like a 'dynamic' solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.sort_index(axis=1)`:

```
result = df1.merge(df2, how='outer').sort_index(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Although MaxU answer might be the right one here, you can always use the following **after** the merge:

```
df[sorted(df.columns)]
```

The reason for this is if you want to use another key (with lambda):

```
df[sorted(df.columns,key=lambda x: x[1:])]
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

cols = 'A,B,C,D,A_x,B_x,C_x,D_x'.split(',')

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
df.loc[0] = list(range(len(cols)))
df[sorted(df.columns)]
```

Returns:

```
   A A_x  B B_x  C C_x  D D_x
0  0   4  1   5  2   6  3   7
```

Comment: oh! i got it now, you want to apply it __after__ it's been merged (in a second step), then it'll work +1

Comment: @MaxU Yep, and the .tolist() was not necessary so I removed that. I also made it clear that you do it after.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Create initial random data.
np.random.seed(0)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=list('ABx'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=list('ABy'))
df = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', suffixes=['', '_x'], left_index=True, right_index=True)


col_order = []
common_columns = df1.columns & df2.columns
for c in common_columns:
    col_order.append(c)
    col_order.append(c + '_x')
# Add non-common columns to right side of dataframe.
col_order.extend([c for c in df if c not in common_columns and not c.endswith('_x')])
>>> df[col_order]
          A       A_x         B       B_x         x         y
0  1.764052  0.333674  0.400157  1.494079  0.978738 -0.205158
1  2.240893  0.313068  1.867558 -0.854096 -0.977278 -2.552990
2  0.950088  0.653619 -0.151357  0.864436 -0.103219 -0.742165
3  0.410599  2.269755  0.144044 -1.454366  1.454274  0.045759
4  0.761038 -0.187184  0.121675  1.532779  0.443863  1.469359
```

Answer (score 0):

Another, possibly generic, solution to reorder columns can be -

```
cols_order = ['A', 'A_x' , 'B' , 'B_x', 'C' , 'C_x', 'D', 'D_x'] 
merge = merge[cols_order]
```

This will simply rewrite the dataframe with the order of columns according to the order in the list, cols_order.